# Доступ к файлу из нескольких потоков java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Файлы потокобезопасные или нужно синхронизировать?

Comment: Чтение - да, запись - нет

Comment: @PavelParshin оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreycha, добавил ответ, но по-моему тут и комментария сполна хватает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой ресурс (файл, область памяти и т.п.) не является потокобезопасным по умолчанию, если предполагается его изменение (в вашем случае - это запись в файл). Чтение данных ресурса всегда потокобезопасно.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы читает файлы, то есть не вносите никаких изменений в исходный файл, то данная процедура потокобезопасна, но если же вы хотите записать данные в файл, то тут уже дела под другому обстоят и еще много зависит от класса. Например, класс FileWtiter - не потокобезоспаный. Тут нужно аккуратно.

Answer (score -2):

```
    //в одном из сервлетов приложения определить метод записи в файл
    //следующим образом, например:
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
    {  
      protected synchronized static void WriteToFile(String stringMessage)
        {
          try
          {
            FileWriter filelog=new FileWriter(new File("полный путь к файлу"),true);
            //запись в файл
            filelog.write(stringMessage);
            filelog.flush();
          }
          catch(Exception error)
          {
            //ошибка
          }
        }
    }

    //использование  нашего метода записи в файл в другом месте приложения 
    //вне текущего сервлета
    MyServlet.WriteToLogFile("текст записываемый в файл");

    //в текущем сервлете
    WriteToLogFile("текст записываемый в файл");
```

Comment: старайтесь делать более развёрнутые ответы...Что значит данный код?..он отвечает на вопрос пользователя? По-моему нет.